# A simplified proof of the uniqueness theorem for finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I'd like to have the following proof verified. Feedback welcome.

Suppose that $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group and $G=\mathbb Z_{r_1} \oplus\cdots \oplus \mathbb Z_{r_s} \oplus F_1$ where $r_1|r_2|\cdots|r_s$ and $F_1$ is a free abelian group. If also $G=\mathbb Z_{w_1} \oplus...\oplus \mathbb Z_{w_t} \oplus F_2$ is another such decomposition, I wish to show that $r_s=w_t, r_{s-1}=w_{t-1},\ldots$ whence $s=t$. We assume that we have already proved that $F_1 \cong F_2$.

To prove my claim, any element of $G/F_1$ of maximal order has order $r_s$ so that any element of maximal order in $G/F_2$ must have order $r_s$ as well, but such as element has already order $w_t$ so that $r_s=w_t$. Using the fact that finite groups are simplifiable as mentioned in the comments below, we deduce that $r_{s-1}= w_{t-1}$, and so on (a few trivial details such as $G/F_1 \cong G/F_2$ have been implicitly used).

Comment: You would need to show that there is an isomorphism between $Z_{r_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus Z_{r_s}$ and $Z_{w_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus Z_{w_t}$ where $(0,0,\ldots,1)$ maps to $(0,0,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: Is it really trivial that $G/F_1 \simeq G/F_2$ ?

Comment: Yes. Torsion subgroups are isomorphic @Max

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure that you weren't using $F_1\simeq F_2 \implies G/F_1\simeq G/F_2$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is showing the existence of such an isomorphism approximately as lengthy as the standard proof?

Comment: @1319m I would expect so ...

Comment: I don't know if you consider that lengthy but my favourite proof of uniqueness uses the fact that $r_s$ is the exponent of $G$ so it must equal $w_t$. Then use the fact that finite groups are simplifiable, i.e. for finite groups $G,H,K, G\times H\simeq G\times K \implies H\simeq K$

Comment: @Max I think what you just stated is equivalent to my method, the only point that I missed was that I did not use the fact that finite groups are simplifiable

Comment: I edited my solution by adding the point you just mentioned. Is this proof correct now? @Max

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I deleted the factoring part and used another fact to complete the proof. What about now?

Comment: If you know how to prove the simplifiability, then yes it should work

Comment: So I think this proof is shorter than the standard proof @Max

Comment: I certainly agree but (I think) many people don't teach the simplifiability before and so they have to find a way around it

Comment: What is your question, 1319m?

Comment: @amWhy it was a proof verification

Comment: Downvoting this post was not fair I think @amWhy

Comment: If you clarifiy that fact in the body of your post, I'll remove my downvote.